# Privilegios phpmyadmin usuario root

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Quiero borrar bases de datos en phpmyadmin pero no hay manera. Hace unos días me aparecía el check box para seleccionar la base de datos y la opción eliminar. Ahora no tengo esa opción. Estoy como root pero creo que se han perdido privilegios  y no se reestablecerlos.

[image: lista de base de datos]

En cuentas de usuario me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: cuentas de usuario]

Pienso que root ha perdido privilegios y por eso no puedo eliminar pero me gustaría reestablecerlos si es que es esto.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado

He añadido la sentencia siguiente en el fichero config.ini.php de la carpeta phpmyadmin.

```
$cfg['AllowUserDropDatabase'] = true;
```